# Adding "i"th elements of each of the inner arrays of an array (2 dimensional) in Python and to make a new array with the addition as the "i"th element

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

#Python Code

```
n = 5
sprints = [2, 4, 1, 3]
s = [[0]*n for i in range(len(sprints)-1)] #array of 5*3
add_arr = [0 for i in range(n)] #array of 5

for i in range((len(sprints)-1)):
    for j in range(n):
        if sprints[i]<sprints[i+1]:
            for k in range(sprints[i]-1,sprints[i+1]):
                s[i][k] = 1
        else:
            for m in range(sprints[i+1]-1,sprints[i]):
                s[i][m] = 1
          
print(s)
```

Output -

```
[[0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0]]
```

I want to add each of the "i"th elements of the inner arrays to create a new array such that:

```
add_arr = [[0+1+1],[1+1+1],[1+1+1],[1+1+0],[0+0+0]] = [2,3,3,2,0]
```

Please Help!

Comment: Don't use builtin `sum` as variable name!!! Now you can't do sum(...).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was unaware that "sum" is a built-in function in Python. I'll make the changes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` and `map`:

```
add_arr = list(map(sum, zip(*s)))
print(add_arr)

[2, 3, 3, 2, 0]
```